# Better Alternative to If-Else in Tcl

Tags: arrays, if-statement, tcl, conditional-statements

I have a table as shown below and I need to code that in Tcl. I tried the if-else code but they become very long and repetitive sentences. Is there a better alternative solution to implement using an array or switch case statement or something like that

```
Table

Number Condition Width Height
2         True     1x    1y
3         True     1x    1y
4         True     1x    2y
5         True     2x    2y
6         True     2x    4y
7         True     3x    4y
2         False    0.2x  1y
3         False    0.2x  1y
4         False    0.2x  1y
5         False    0.2x  1y
6         False    0.2x  1y
7         False    0.2x  1y
```

Basically, this width and height I am checking against a standard known value so I am using a mod function to store a value into variable and then apply condition for the same.

For Example: Lets consider the known value is 100 and 1x = 10 and 1y = 20
Both 10 and 20 are divisible by 100 so mod function will return 0 obviously.

So, I will check something like this:

```
set knownvalue 100
set 1x 10
set 1y 20
set offset_x [expr ($knownvalue % $1x)]
$> 0                                # (return 0)
set offset_y [expr ($knownvalue % $1y)]
$> 0                                #(returns 0)`

#  (Note as per chart for number 2, Height becomes 2y so that needs to be accounted for when calculating $offset_2y)
```

In real life this 1x and 1 y for the table shown above will change and hence I am using the following code technique:

```
if {condition == true} {
     if {(number ==2 || number ==3) && ( $offset_x != 0)} {
     puts "Error"
     }
     if {number ==4 && ($offset_x !=0 || $offset_2y != 0)} {
     puts "Error"                                   
     }
     ..... complete till number ==7
} else {
    if {(number ==2 || number ==3 || number ==4 ... number ==7) && (offset_0.2x !=0 ||         $offset_1y !=0 )} {
    puts "Error"
}
```

This works although, is not the most optimal solution to implement this. So, please suggest something better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can structure your table such that checking for membership of a particular category is a collection of equality tests, you can convert that to an associative array lookup. If you make the content of the variables in the associative array be scripts, you can then just compute which code you want to evaluate and use that.

```
set action(2,true,0,0) {error "Something went wrong"}
#...

eval $action($number,$condition,[expr {$offset_x % 10}],[expr {$offset_y % 42}])
```

However, this *only* works if you can structure things so that you are doing an exact string lookup. In particular, the above might be like you are doing:

```
if {($number eq "2") && ($condition eq "true") && ($offset_x % 10 eq "0") && ($offset_y % 42 eq "0")} {
    error "Something went wrong"
} else ...
```

Failing that, try the `switch` command. That can at least support default cases and glob patterns:

```
switch -- $number,$condition,[expr {$offset_x % 10}],[expr {$offset_y % 42}] {
    2,true,0,0 - 7,false,1,19 {
        error "Something went wrong"
    }
    default {
        puts "nothing else applicable"
    }
}
```

```
switch -glob -- $number,$condition,[expr {$offset_x % 10}],[expr {$offset_y % 42}] {
    2,true,0,* - 7,false,*,19 {
        error "Something went wrong"
    }
    default {
        puts "nothing else applicable"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also mix and match, with `if` and `switch` and array lookup, depending on which is best for you.